# Как получить поля формы с multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, maven, servlet, fileupload, multipart

Как можно использовать `multipart/form-data` для загрузки аватарки пользователя, но при этом я не могу снять данные с полей формы обычным способом. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Класс в котором я снимаю данные с формы:

```
public class RegistrationInfo{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationInfo.class);

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public RegistrationInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return request.getParameter(FIELD_FIRST_NAME);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return request.getParameter(FIELD_LAST_NAME);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        LOG.debug("email: " + request.getParameter(FIELD_EMAIL));
        return request.getParameter(FIELD_EMAIL);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        LOG.debug("pass: " + request.getParameter(FIELD_PASSWORD));
        return request.getParameter(FIELD_PASSWORD);
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return request.getParameter(FIELD_CONFIRM_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Но при такой реализации я получаю `NullPointerException`. Каким способ мне можно получать данные с формы?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/3212712

Answer (score 1):

Таким способом вы не сможете снять параметры с реквеста. Тип контента `multipart/form-data` вызывает необходимость парсить тело реквеста по частям. То есть если вы пытаетесь получить параметры с помощью [`ServletRequest.getParameter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)):

> Возвращает значение параметра запроса как `String` или `null`, если
>   параметр не существует. Параметры запроса - дополнительная информация,
>   отправленная с запросом. Для HTTP-сервлетов параметры содержатся в
>   строке запроса или в теле запроса где размещены данные формы.

то вы получаете `null` потому что тело реквеста имеет другой формат, а вышеупомянутый метод работает если тело реквеста имеет формат `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

---

Более детальная информация о [методе `POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST):

> Метод HTTP `POST` отправляет данные на сервер. Тип тела запроса
>   указывается заголовком `Content-Type`.
>
> Разница между `PUT` и `POST` заключается в том, что `PUT` является
>   идемпотентным: вызов его один или несколько раз подряд имеет тот же
>   эффект (который не является побочным эффектом), где последовательный
>   идентичный `POST` может иметь дополнительные эффекты, например,
>   несколько раз передавать те же данные.
>
> Запрос `POST` обычно отправляется через форму HTML и приводит к
>   изменению на сервере. В этом случае тип содержимого выбирается путем
>   размещения соответствующей строки в атрибуте `enctype` элемента
>   `<form>` или атрибута `formenctype` элементов `<input>` или
>   `<button>`:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: ключи и значения закодированы
>     в кортежах с ключом, разделенных символом `&`, с `=` между ключом и
>     значением. Не буквенно-цифровые символы в обоих ключах и значениях
>     кодируются в процентах: это причина, по которой этот тип не подходит
>     для использования с двоичными данными (вместо этого используйте
>     `multipart/form-data`);
> - `multipart/form-data`;
> - `text/plain`.

---

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность снять параметры и части файлов с реквеста, вы можете использовать анотацию [`@MultipartConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html):

> Аннотация, которая может быть поставлена на класс `Servlet`, указывающая
>   на то, что экземпляры сервлета ожидают запросы, соответствующие типу
>   MIME с `multipart/form-data`.
>
> Сервлеты, аннотированные с помощью `MultipartConfig`, могут извлекать
>   компоненты `Part` заданного запроса `multipart/form-data`, вызывая
>   `getPart()` или `getParts()`.

---

Вы также можете почитать об аннотации [MultipartConfig в тюториале](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html).

В котором также можно найти [пример `fileupload`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) использования этой аннотации.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)