# Как можно передать данные в сервлет или jsp и вывести их?

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet

Есть форма на стартовой странице. На этой форме поля ввода данных и две кнопки `submit`. Вот сама форма:

```
<form name="main form" method="post" action="Servlet" onsubmit="redirect(this)">
<label>Введите функцию</label>
<input type="text" name="function"> <br> 
<label>Введите начальное значения х</label>
<input type="text" name="xmin"> <br>
<label>Введите шаг изминения значения х</label>
<input type="text" name="dx"> <br>
<label>Введите гранчное значение х</label>
<input type="text" name="xmax"> <br>
<label>Переадресация на JSP</label>
<input type="submit" name="JSPButton" style="background: brown"></input> 
<br>
<label>Переадресация на Servlet</label>
<input type="submit" name="ServletButton" style="background: aqua"></input> 
<br>
</form>
```

Она переадресовывает пользователя на промежуточный сервлет, в котором я проверяю, какая кнопка была нажата и в зависимости от этого направляю пользователя либо на сервлет с таблицей либо на `jsp`-страничку с такой же таблицей.

```
public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    Enumeration fields =request.getParameterNames();
    if (fields.hasMoreElements()){
        while (fields.hasMoreElements()){
            String field = (String) fields.nextElement();
            String name = request.getParameter(field);

            if (name == "xmin"){
                request.setAttribute("xmin", request.getParameterValues("xmin"));
            }

            if(field.equals("JSPButton")){
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/LW4_war_exploded/jsp");
            }
            if(field.equals("ServletButton")){response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/LW4_war_exploded/TableServlet");}
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно каким-то образом получить все данные, которые ввели в форму, протащить их сначала в промежуточный сервлет, а затем в jsp или на сервлет. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890041/204920

Answer (score 0):

вот так:

```
 String function = request.getParameter("function")

 ...

 response.sendRedirect("TableServlet");

 ...
```

там так же из request читаете

Данные которые хотите передать на страницу  кладете в атрибуты ответа

```
  response.setAttribute("name", val);
```

пример можно посмотреть здесь https://codesjava.com/servlet-sendredirect-example

Comment: @Z_John Если я делаю через request.getParameter(...) передается null