# Как загрузить несколько файлов Spring MVC с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Вроде, с серверной стороной разобалась(примерно):

```
    @PostMapping("/my")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public TaskOutDto reviewTask(@RequestBody @Valid TaskInDto dto,
                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
//task это какое-то задание, которое пользователь выполнил и отослал на ревью
        Task reviewedTask = mapper.fromDto(dto);
        reviewedTask.setStatus(TaskStatus.IN_REVIEW);

//так же пользователь прикрепляет фото пруфы к своему таску, чтобы админ наверяка убедился что задание выполнено
        List<Photo> photosToSave = Streams.zip(
//Здесь мы маппим два стрима: один с файлами multipart, второй с файлами куда мы будем перегонять их 
                Arrays.stream(multipartFiles),
                Arrays.stream(multipartFiles)
                        .map(file -> UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + file.getOriginalFilename())
                        .map(fileName -> new File(uploadPath + "/" + fileName)),
                ((multipartFile, file) -> {
                    try {
                        multipartFile.transferTo(file);
                        return file.getName();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new ApplicationException("");
                    }
                }
//в итоге получается что-то типа: получаем массив  файлов с клиента сохраняем их все себе, а названия файлов сохраняем в бд и привязываем их к конкретному заданию
                )).map(fileName -> new Photo(fileName, reviewedTask))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        reviewedTask.setPhotos(photosToSave);
        taskService.save(reviewedTask);
        photosRepository.saveAll(photosToSave);

//возвращаем итоговый результат: задание с айдишником, фотки
        return mapper.toDto(reviewedTask);
    }
```

У меня возникли проблемы с клиентской стороной: мне необходимо отправить и dto в виде json, и неопределенное количество файлов, в одном запросе. Пока у меня сть только это:

```
<div class="card text-center mt-3">
                    <div class="card-header" data-position="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="title"></h5>
                        <input type="hidden" id="taskId">
                        <p class="card-text" id="description"></p>
                        <label for="photosCount">Photos should be:</label>
                        <p class="card-text" id="photosCount"></p>
                        <a onclick="askForReview(url)" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ask for review</a>
                        <p onclick="getComments(this)" class="text-primary mb-4">Comments</p>
<!--                        <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label">Upload photos</label>-->
<!--                        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFileMultiple" multiple>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
=========================
function askForReview(url) {
    let taskOutDto = {
        "task_id": $("#taskId").val(),
        "title": $("#title").text(),
        "description": $("#description").text(),
        "status": $(".card").children(".card-header").text(),
        "position": $(".card").children(".card-header").attr("data-position"),
        "photos_count": $("#photosCount").text()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url + '/my',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(taskOutDto),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
//эта функция просо заполняет данные на странице полученные с сервера
                fillAndShowTaskInfo(response);
            },
            401: function () {
//эта функция обновляет access token
                let refreshed = refreshToken();
                if (refreshed) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url + '/my',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(taskOutDto),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            fillAndShowTaskInfo(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            403: function () {
                window.location = '../403_forbidden.html';
            }
        }
    })
}
```

В общем, половина скрипта не сильно важна. Необходимо как-то приклеить массив файлов (разметка которая закомментирована) к ajax-запросу, вместе с dto. Может кто-то знает, как это провернуть? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Так делать нельзя. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890041/204920) есть ответ.