# Spring MVC upload file java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Имеется Spring MVC приложение. Пытаюсь в нем загрузить файл. Методы контроллера выглядят так:

```
@RequestMapping("/addNewListening")
    public ModelAndView addNewListening() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin-views/add-listening-task");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView upload(
            @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("successUpload");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

JSP c формой:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select file to upload: <br />
<form action="/admin/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input   name="file" type="file"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

В конфиг классе прописаны бины:

```
@Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipart = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipart.setMaxUploadSize(3 * 1024 * 1024);
        return multipart;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
        MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
        multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
        return multipartFilter;
    }
```

При запуск приложения
я пытаюсь загрузить файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и при нажатии кнопки "Upload file" я получаю:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected headers to be terminated by an empty line.

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected headers to be terminated by an empty line.
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Какой участок кода еще нужно сбросить? Заранее спасибо

upd. Server log:

```
11:48:23.800 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /admin/upload
11:48:23.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=admin@ukr.net, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5CFAEA37E4FFADEB41C85FBB59010D53], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]]]
11:48:23.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=admin@ukr.net, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5CFAEA37E4FFADEB41C85FBB59010D53], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]]]
11:48:23.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorized filter invocation [POST /admin/upload] with attributes [authenticated]
11:48:23.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured POST /admin/upload
11:48:23.802 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - POST "/admin/upload", parameters={}
11:48:23.896 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected headers to be terminated by an empty line.
11:48:23.897 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Что я вижу в браузере:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected headers to be terminated by an empty line.

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected headers to be terminated by an empty line.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected headers to be terminated by an empty line.
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseEndOfLine(FileUploadBase.java:660)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getParsedHeaders(FileUploadBase.java:582)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1052)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:1017)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:309)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:333)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:159)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:143)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.67
```

Сам http запрос:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/admin/upload
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Language: ru
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2023 14:07:48 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15009
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryADgDv5A0ZKq6wkNK
Cookie: JSESSIONID=B4E4437FA7A9A4E4A82EE78119DAA924
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/admin/addNewListening
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Точно не знаю, в чем ошибка. Но могу предположить, что дело в action в тэгэ form. Думаю, там должен стоять атрибут th:action="@{/admin/upload}". Вот пример моего [проекта](https://github.com/ruslooob/HabrXX/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/publication-form.html#L13), где я сделал похожую задачу и у меня работала загрузка файла.

Comment: Отличный пример, в котором пользователь не пытается поломать  используемую по умолчанию конфигурацию загрузки файла. В вопросе не хватает многих деталей, даже нет стэктрейса ошибки. Предлагаю переписать код под сервлеты. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/890041/204920) пример как можно загружать файл с помощью сервлета.

Comment: @РусланМамедов у меня в проекте не используется таймлиф, да и тег action похоже как работает, ведь при нажатии кнопки, я перехожу в браузере на нужную мне URL, но метод в контроллер классе не начинает свою работу, так-как, видимо, какая-та проблема с параметром, который он ожидает.

Comment: @RomanC не был уверен, какую информацию стоило добавить в вопрос, чтобы он не оказался бесконечным. Добавил лог сервера и стектрейс ошибки. В том то и дело, что не сработал обычный копипаст с tutorial. Фактически я ничего не менял. Просто что-то в моем проекте мешает работе, наверняка, но по стектрейсу я не могу определить что конкретно

Comment: Если ошибка связана с парсингом запроса, то надо предоставить информацию по запросу, привести пример кода, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку. В таком виде, в котором вы поставили вопрос никто разбираться не будет.  Все знают, что загрузка в спринге работает нормально и без дополнительной конфигурации, которая на мой взгляд абсолютно бессмыслена. Нужно описывать проблему полностью, что вы делали, что код вызывает ошибку. Ошибка в том, что в заголовках отправляемых с запросом нет конца строки. Как можно создать такой запрос, в котором неверные заголовки? Вряд ли здесь кто-то сможет ответить.

Comment: Добавил заголовки. Это содержимое http запроса, которое передается при нажатии на кноку загрузить файл. Но метод @RequestMapping не срабатывает ((( Так и не победил беду((

Comment: @RomanC по-идеи теперь вся информация о том какой запрос обрабатывается или еще нужна какая? Может добавить проект на git hub для убобности вопроизведения?

Comment: @had0uken Можешь добавить ссылку на GitHub, но ссылка ничего не значит. В вопрос надо писать только релевантный код, проблему надо описывать так чтобы мы понимали что ты понимаешь суть проблемы. Вопросы почему этот код не работает, без понимания проблемы и возможности ее решить самостоятельно бесполезен.

Comment: ну так а смысл бы мне был обращаться на этот ресурс, если бы я мог решить проблему самостоятельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не разобрался в чем беда: изменил код кусочками из проекта найденного на гите и все заработало:

```
@Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
```

в WebInitializer:

```
private int maxUploadSizeInMb = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // 20 MB
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    // upload temp file will put here
    File uploadDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

    // register a MultipartConfigElement
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement =
            new MultipartConfigElement(uploadDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                    maxUploadSizeInMb, maxUploadSizeInMb * 2, maxUploadSizeInMb / 2);

    registration.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
}
```

если вдруг кому-когда пригодится